# Item not update or deleted when the button is selected

Tags: android

I would like to update / delete a item by it id.

When I try my code, 
after I select on "update button", nothing is being updated.

When I try on "delete button", nothing is being deleted too.

I would like to delete my items based on it ID.
I'm using basecolumns._ID in androidOpenDBHelper.

logcat for my update part:

```
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE fuelLog SET tcost=?,fuelprice=?,fcon=?,odometer=?,date=?,preodometer=?,fuelpump=? WHERE _id=? AND date+=?
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:649)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1563)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at com.example.fuellogproject.updateAnddelete.updateLog(updateAnddelete.java:499)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at com.example.fuellogproject.updateAnddelete.onClick(updateAnddelete.java:411)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17356)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-27 01:13:39.676: E/AndroidRuntime(29370):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my code.

```
private void updateLog(fuelLogPojo updatefuelLogPojo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelper = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            // ContentValues class is used to store a set of values
            //It is like name-value pairs
            // "value" part contains the values that we are going to UPDATE
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE, dateEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE, priceEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL, pumpEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST, costTextViewValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM, odometerEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PREODM, preodometerEditTextValue);
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON, fconTextViewValue);

            // If we are using multiple whereClauseArguments, array size should have to change
            String[] whereClauseArgument = new String[1];
            whereClauseArgument[0] = updatefuelLogPojo.getdate();

            System.out.println("whereClauseArgument[0] is :" + whereClauseArgument[0]);

            /**
             * This is the normal SQL query for UPDATE
            UPDATE table_name
            SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
            WHERE some_column=some_value
            */      

            sqliteDatabase.update(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, contentValues, BaseColumns._ID+"=? AND date+=?", whereClauseArgument);
            // For two whereClauseArguments
            //sqliteDatabase.update(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, contentValues, BaseColumns._ID+"=? AND name=?", whereClauseArgument);

            sqliteDatabase.close();
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? How do you know they aren't updated? Do you log anything to see what the new records are? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @codeMagic I didn't log, there is no error

Comment: Ok, so again, "How do you know they aren't updated?".

Comment: @codeMagic I'm display the item on the listview, based on the date.
when I want to edit them/update them, I want to based on the id. initially, the update is based on date. However, after I change to id, it doesn't update anything

Comment: @codeMagic I've a listview. after I press update, it will show in the listview the updated records. But, in my list view, is it not updated

Comment: We are starting to get somewhere. How do you tell the `ListView` to update its contents? Maybe you should post that part of the code also.

Comment: @codeMagic I'm trying out something, will update the code in a while

Comment: @codeMagic I've just edited my answer

Comment: Its a question but I will look ;)

Answer (score 0):

whereClauseArgument is an array of String but in here you havnt any index!
sqliteDatabase.delete(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, BaseColumns._ID+"=?", whereClauseArgument);

i am not certain issue to be of this. but have a look.
may be you must write like this :
sqliteDatabase.delete(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, BaseColumns._ID+"=", whereClauseArgument[0]);

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE _id=? AND date+=?
```

There seems to be an extra `+` there causing the syntax error.